# java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: (conn=15) Too many tables; MariaDB can only use 61 tables in a join

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mariadb

I'm a beginner with JPA, and whilst accessing the database from my DAO, an error stating MariaDB being limited to 61 tables in a join pops up.

Here's a portion of an Entity's code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "service")
@NamedQuery(name = "Department.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Department d")
public class Department implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "nom")
    private String name;

    private byte status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<OperatingBloc> operatingBlocs;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "depatment", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Room> rooms;
    ...
}
```

And a model of my DAO's code

```
@Stateless
public class DepartmentDAO implements DepartmentDAORemote, DepartmentDAOLocal {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Department> getAllDepartments() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Department.findAll", Department.class).getResultList();
    }
    ...
}
```

Each time I would access the `getAllDepartments()` methods of my DAO for maybe more than twice or three times, I'd get the following error

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet 
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: (conn=15) Too many tables; MariaDB can only use 61 tables in a join
...
```

I have an overall of 40 tables thus 40 entities and each entity has its DAO coded the same way as the one above, so my question relates to anything I could've done wrong and how would I correct it.

Using JPA 2.2, MariaDB for the database.

Comment: Using `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` will make Hibernate join many tables. Try using `FetchType.LAZY` instead.

Comment: Yeah, but setting ```fetch = FetchType.EAGER```, made things easier to initialize the Sets or Collections without any more code in the DAO. When I set it to ```FetchType.LAZY``` I pretty much get this exception, 
```failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: Department.users, could not initialize proxy - no Session```. 
Any advice?